# Segmentation fault on running spring boot application via docker desktop

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a spring boot application as 'users' and when I am trying to bring up the application via docker, it's failing with segmentation fault and exit with code 139 as below: Please advise.

```
Starting docker compose
Container users-user-db-1  Creating
Container users-solace-1  Creating
Container users-solace-1  Created
Container users-user-db-1  Created
Container users-users-1  Creating
Container users-users-1  Created
Attaching to users-users-1, users-solace-1, users-user-db-1
users-user-db-1  | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
users-user-db-1  | This user must also own the server process.
users-user-db-1  |
users-user-db-1  | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
users-user-db-1  | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
users-user-db-1  | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
users-user-db-1  |
users-user-db-1  | Data page checksums are disabled.
users-user-db-1  |
users-user-db-1  | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
users-user-db-1  | creating subdirectories ... ok
users-user-db-1  | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
users-user-db-1  | selecting default max_connections ... 100
users-solace-1              | Host Boot ID: 
users-solace-1              | Starting VMR Docker Container: Wed Apr 5 08:21:32 UTC 2023
users-solace-1              | Setting umask to 077
users-solace-1              | SolOS Version: soltr_9.9.0.34
users-user-db-1  | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
users-user-db-1  | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
users-user-db-1  | creating configuration files ... ok
users-user-db-1  | running bootstrap script ... ok
users-users-1          | Segmentation fault
users-users-1 exited with code 0
```

docker-compose.sh looks like below:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker container rm -f $(docker container ls -aq)

mvn clean install -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true

docker build --no-cache -f Dockerfile.local -t users:latest .

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up --build
```

dockerfile.local looks like below:

```
FROM <url>/openjdk:11-jdk
MAINTAINER users

ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar

COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

CMD java -jar /app.jar

EXPOSE 8080
```

docker-compose.yml looks like below :

```
version: '3'
services:
  users:
    image: users:latest
    restart: on-failure
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - users.svc
    links:
      - user-db
      - solace
    ports:
      - "8094:8080"
    depends_on:
      - user-db
      - solace
    environment:
      WAIT_HOSTS: solace.svc:8080, user-db.svc:5432
      USERS_DB_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://user-db.svc:5432/users
      USERS_DB_APP_USER_NAME: USERS_rwuser
      USERS_DB_APP_USER_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
      USERS_DB_MIGRATION_USER_NAME: USERS_rwuser
      USERS_DB_MIGRATION_USER_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
      USERS_DB_READ_WRITE_USER_ROLE: USERS_rwuser
      USERS_DB_READ_ONLY_USER_ROLE: USERS_rwuser
      SOLACE_HOST_URL: tcp://solace.svc:55555
      SOLACE_MSG_VPN: default
      USERS_SOLACE_USERNAME: admin
      USERS_SOLACE_PASSWORD: admin
    command: >
          java -jar /app.jar"

  user-db:
    image: <URL>/postgres:12.4
    restart: always
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - user-db.svc
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: USERS_rwuser
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
      POSTGRES_DB: users

  solace:
    image: <URL>/solace/solace-pubsub-standard:9.9.0.34
    restart: always
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - solace.svc
    shm_size: 1g
    ulimits:
      core: 1
      nofile:
        soft: 2448
        hard: 38048
    environment:
      - system_scaling_maxconnectioncount=100
```

Comment: I have similar issue after updating to Spring Boot 2.7.9.

Comment: @JanCizmar Seems like this issue is related to less size of RAM of your machine

Comment: Well, do you think reducing the heap size would help?